# Access query returns no results when criterion added

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am running the following query in Access 2010

```
SELECT 
    [Table1].[Field4], TABLE2.ID, TABLE2.["Fielld1"],
    TABLE2.["Field3"], TABLE2.["Field2"]
FROM 
    TABLE2 
INNER JOIN 
    [Table1] ON TABLE2.ID = [Table1].[Field4]
WHERE 
    TABLE2.["Field3"]="XX"
```

It runs perfectly without the WHERE clause, but returns no results when the WHERE clause is added. I know that the records exist. Any ideas?

Comment: it means there are no rows in your tables that match the `where` clause

Comment: or that it fails to match the where clause and the join.  Perhaps post some sample data

Comment: @vkp - Did you see this *I know that the records exist*

Comment: Are you sure field3 doen't have a "hidden" character, or maybe a space with the XX?  Change the where to `WHERE TABLE2.["Field3"] like"*XX*"` does it appear now? or maybe... `WHERE TRIM(TABLE2.["Field3"])="XX"`

Comment: Do those fields really include quotes in their names: *"Fielld1"*; *"Field3"*; and so forth?  If not, discard the quotes from the field names in your query ... ie `TABLE2.[Fielld1]` instead of `TABLE2.["Fielld1"]`  But there may still be something more going on because I don't see how the query would work correctly with quoted field names even without the `WHERE` clause.